# Sub category text in the URL of wordpress site

Tags: seo, urls

I am launching a site about mobile and it is in **wordpress**.

URL structure is as follow

example.com/unlock/company/model

example.com/how-to/company/model

**Unlock** and **how to** are **parent category** and **company** is **subcategory** of both. 
Now I have to create the company subcategory twice for both the parent category. In that case slug will be different.

for eg.

example.com/unlock/apple/something

example.com/how-to/apple_/something

Apple is present in both the unlock and how to category. Same slug cannot be used, so I am using **apple** for unlock and **apple_** for how to, as same **slug** cannot be used.

I am try to get a user friendly URL. But does it effect the SEO negatively?

Comment: Have you enabled/modified [Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)?

Comment: Permalinks has been modified. But site is still not live. It is in development mode.